# Issue with running CLI custom command built with nestjs-commander in NX monorepo

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nest-commander

I want to write a very simple custom command that can be run in command line. I used [nest-commander](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/nest-commander) as it's officially suggested in the docs.

So I followed tutorial from nestjs and tried to execute it (instructions are [here](https://nest-commander.jaymcdoniel.dev/docs/executing/local/)) but it failed.

```
ts-node apps/api/src/main.ts basic
```

First, I've got `Cannot use import statement outside a module` error

```
(node:12444) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[path]\apps\api\src\main.ts:1
import { __awaiter } from "tslib";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
```

So I've modified my `apps/api/tsconfig.json` to alter configuration for ts-node.

```
  ...
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  ...
```

But it still not working - now I get another error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@myapp/db'
Require stack:
...
```

So it seems that it ignores root `tsconfig.base.json`. Not sure how to approach this one

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer - I had to pass the `-r tsconfig-paths/register` option and tsconfig filepath explicitly to make it work. Now it looks like this:

```
ts-node --project apps/api/tsconfig.app.json -r tsconfig-paths/register apps/api/src/cli.ts
```